# Not able to generate arc in d3,js for some values,

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using d3.js to generate a circle kind of graph. My graph has three layers background,midground and foreground. I have a function called **call** for foreground and midground layer.

I am able to generate the arc for values till .96 but if it goes beyond that .97, .98, .99 and 1.0 arc are getting collapsed.

```
midground.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(arcTween, 0. * τ);

foreground.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(arcTween, 0. * τ);
```

I am new to d3.js and svg kindly help with this. I have provided the jsfiddle link as well.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lxnymj28/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This setting is messing up the `arc` calculation:

```
.cornerRadius(outerRadius - innerRadius)
```

If you remove the cornerRadius, [everything draws fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxnymj28/67/).

**EDITS**

Did some research, this was a bug in the [library](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2183), fixed back in October, 2015.  You are using way out of date software.

If you use the latest version of d3.js version 3, everything works fine.

New fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxnymj28/68/).

Comment: But I want the curves at the end. Is there any way to show the arc smoothly without mess.

Comment: Worked like a gem.